# loading * no listener in gwan linux 32-bit

Tags: listener, file-permissions, g-wan

GWAN error on Centos 7 version

I tried both version 64 bit and 32 bit version , I am using latest version from GWAN site.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] user: root (uid:0), group: root (uid:0)
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] system  fd_max: 110,032
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] program fd_max: 110,032
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] updated fd_max: 500,000
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] Available network interfaces (2):
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] 127.0.0.1
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] 10.21.150.98
[Fri Nov 21 18:02:32 2014 GMT] * no listener in /opt/gwan_linux32-bit
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] G-WAN 4.3.14 32-bit (Mar 14 2013 07:34:53)
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] ------------------------------------------------
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] Local Time: Fri, 21 Nov 2014 13:17:57 GMT-5
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] RAM: (1.11 GiB free + 0 shared + 0 buffers) / 3.53 GiB total
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] Physical Pages: 1.11 GiB / 3.53 GiB
[Fri Nov 21 18:17:57 2014 GMT] DISK: 19.14 GiB free / 19.55 GiB total
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in your log file:

> - no listener in /opt/gwan_linux32-bit

This is likely to be a [file permission issue](http://gwan.ch/faq#listener). Also, try to rename this folder as `gwan32` as old versions had trouble with names matching the naming patterns used by listeners.

Note: the version you are using is quite old: *G-WAN 4.3.14 (March 14 2013)*, registered users have access to far more recent releases that add features and patches for system (OS versions, LIBC versions, Hypervisors...) incompatibilities.

Comment: What do you mean by registered user? I don't see any way to register and download the latest version ? is it paid version ? How much i need to pay .

Comment: I tried to do what you instructed but dint work.  Does it work on Centos 7 ? is there any pre-requesite to make it work something like some libs ?

Comment: Any missing library would be explicitely requested by the system. We are also using CentOS on some servers so this is most likely a **system configuration** issue. Did you use the default listener or did you create your own? Try to narrow the problem to identify the cause of this issue.